# Evaluating this integral : $ \int \frac {1-7\cos^2x} {\sin^7x \cos^2x} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

The question :

$$ \int \frac {1-7\cos^2x} {\sin^7x \cos^2x} dx $$

I tried dividing by $\cos^2 x$ and splitting the fraction.

That turned out to be complicated(Atleast for me!)

How do I proceed now?

Answer (score 4):

Make the substitution $\cos(x)=u$ to get:
$$\int\frac{7u^2-1}{u^2(1-u^2)^4}du$$

Comment: What will be the next step? This doesn't seem trivial to me.

Comment: @Inceptio Partial fractions ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Does it yield the answer? There might be a easier way, right?

Comment: @Inceptio I don;t understand

Comment: Seriously?? Partial fractions for *THIS*? You'll get linear equations in so many variables, and trying to solve for them alone will be tedious

Comment: According to Mathematica, the answer is not quite trivial, so partial fractions _is_ the way to go, at least from this result.

Comment: @Amr: Solving linear equation as Parth says would be tedious.

Comment: @ParthtHAkkar Note that the integral itself had a power of $7$ in the first place

Comment: @Inceptio The other option is to use reduction formulae to find the last integral

Comment: this is the solution given by wolfram:http://ft2.dtupload.com/24/1.gif Even more complicated

Comment: @VijayRaghavan I think you forgot to add the link

Comment: @Amr I did.It's there

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it should be $u^{3/2}$ and not $u^3$ at the denominator.

Comment: @Julien you may be right. I was doing the substitution in my head

Answer (score 4):

The integration is $$\int \frac{dx}{\sin^7x\cos^2x}-\int\csc^7xdx$$

Using [this](http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction_3.html) repeatedly,  $$\frac{m-1}{n+1}\int\sin^{m-2}\cos^n dx=\frac{\sin^{m-1}x\cos^{n+1}x}{m+n}+\int \sin^mx\cos^n dx,$$

$$\text{we can reach from }\int \frac{dx}{\sin^7x\cos^2x}dx\text{ to } \int \frac{\sin xdx}{\cos^2x}dx$$

Now use [the Reduction Formula](http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction_5.html) of $\int\csc^nxdx$ for the second/last integral

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1-7\cos^2 x}{\sin^7 x\cos^2 x} = \int\frac{\sin^2 x-6\cos^2 x}{\sin^7 x\cos^2 x}dx$

$\displaystyle I = \int\frac{\sin^7 x-6\sin^5 x\cos^2 x}{\sin^{12}x\cos^2 x}dx =  -\int \bigg[\frac{1}{(\sin^ 6 x\cos x)^2}\bigg]'dx = -\frac{1}{\sin^6 x\cos x}+\mathcal{C} $

Comment: This is the best answer according to me (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts,

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sin^7x\cos^2x}=\int \csc^7x\sec^2xdx=\csc^7x\int \sec^2xdx-\int\left( \frac{d\csc^7x}{dx}\cdot \sec^2xdx \right)dx$$
$$=\csc^7x\cdot\tan x-\int\left(7\csc^6x(-\csc x\cot x)\tan x\right)dx$$

$$=\csc^7x\cdot\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+7\int \csc^7xdx$$

$$=\csc^6x\cdot \sec x+7\int\frac{dx}{\sin^7xdx}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The comment really didn't notify me. This is more direct. (+1)